# Showing a function is in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lp-spaces

Given that $f\in L^p(\mathbb{R}),g\in L^q(\mathbb{R})$, $1\le p,q\le\infty.$ Define $F(x)=\int_0^xf(t)dt$.

How can  one show $$(\vert x\vert+1)^{-a}F(x)g(x)\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$$ when $a>2-\frac{1}{p}-\frac{1}{q}$

I can show that $F$ is continuous. I cannot use Holder's inequality since $p$ and $q$ are not conjugate. Integration by parts came to mind but I am not familiar with an analogue of this method for Lebesgue integral functions. Even if I assume that $p,q$ are conjugate it doesn't help much since $f$ is not in the integrand.

Comment: Apologies for the pedantry, but shouldn't the definition of $F$ be $F(x) = \int_0^x f(t) \, dt$?  [i.e., don't you need a dummy variable?]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that $|F(x)|\le|x|^{1-1/p}\|f\|_p$ since Jensen (or Hölder) says
$$
\begin{align}
\left|\int_0^xf(t)\,\mathrm{d}t\right|
&\le|x|^{1-1/p}\left(\int_0^x|f(t)|^p\,\mathrm{d}t\right)^{1/p}\\
&\le(|x|+1)^{1-1/p}\left(\int_0^x|f(t)|^p\,\mathrm{d}t\right)^{1/p}\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\left|(|x|+1)^{-a}F(x)g(x)\right|\le(|x|+1)^{1-a-1/p}\|f\|_p|g(x)|\tag{2}
$$
We know that $(|x|+1)^{1-a-1/p}\in L^r$ for $1-a-\frac1p\lt-\frac1r$.

Hölder says that if $\frac1q=1-\frac1r\gt2-a-\frac1p$, then $(2)\in L^1$. Thus, if
$$
a\gt2-\frac1q-\frac1p\tag{3}
$$
then $(|x|+1)^{-a}F(x)g(x)\in L^1$.